# Show that there two nodes with $k$ edge-disjoint paths connecting them

Tags: graph-theory

I do not know how to solve this exercise:

> Let $G(V,E)$ be a simple undirected graph with $\lvert V(G)\rvert  \ge 2$ and $deg(v) \ge k$ for all $v \in V(G)$. Show that there are two nodes $s$ and $t$ in $G$ such that $s$ and $t$ are connected by at least $k$ edge-disjoint paths. Is the claim also true if $G$ has exactly one node $w$ with $deg(w) < k$.

We have recently done Gomory-Hu trees in class, so I suppose this should be used here, but I do not see how. Could you give me a hint?

Comment: $k$ is not defined anywhere in the hypotheses. Maybe you meant for the degrees to be at least $k$, rather than at least two? Also, $n$ is nowhere defined.

Comment: Yes, sorry; I made an edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Menger's theorem, your problem is equivalent to finding two vertices $s$ and $t$ such that the size $\lambda_{s,t}$ of a minimum $s-t$ cut is at least $k$. Let $s$ be a leaf in a Gomory-Hu tree of $G$ and let $t$ be its unique neighbour in the tree. Then by the properties of Gomory-Hu trees, $\lambda_{s,t}$ is the number of edges crossing the cut $(\{s\}, V-\{s\})$; but this is just $\deg(s) \geq k$.

Since a tree has at least two leaves, the same proof works in the case when there is a single vertex with degree less than $k$.